# Spring MVC Hello World app gives 404 errors on AWS elastic beanstalk, runs as expected locally

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

The application runs fine locally in my IDE (IntelliJ Community Edition). I can run the application, go to my browser, type in `localhost:8080` and it shows me "Hello World"

On AWS, I went to the Software configuration section and added an environment variable `SERVER_PORT` and set it to 8080.

I believe I selected Tomcat when I was prompted for what type of beanstalk configuration I wanted.

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.lizardgizzards</groupId>
    <artifactId>langsite</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>langsite</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <start-class>com.lizardgizzards.langsite.LangsiteApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45327847/133298) and followed the directions there, so now my main class looks like this:

```
package com.lizardgizzards.langsite;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class LangsiteApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(LangsiteApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LangsiteApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I would paste the logs but that exceeds the character limit for stack overflow. I did `ctrl+f` in the log output and searched for "error" and "severe" and "fatal" and didn't see any results.

There are a few warnings such as:

`[Sun Oct 13 18:26:14.321734 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 3396:tid 139962572781632] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]`

`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=64m; support was removed in 8.0`

`[Sun Oct 13 18:41:58.389785 2019] [proxy:warn] [pid 4934:tid 140166163138304] [client 178.73.215.171:54277] AH01092: no HTTP 0.9 request (with no host line) on incoming request and preserve host set forcing hostname to be ip-172-31-18-139.us-west-1.compute.internal for uri /`

`13-Oct-2019 18:36:07.679 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]`

When generating the war file, I use the following maven command: `mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage`

Answer (score 1):

Kind of ridiculous... but here's what fixed it:

I changed the Java version to match the version of Java on AWS:

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
```